# How to get list of contents from folder using contentsOfDirectoryAtPath in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I want to fetch all contents of the folder and add to a submenu of NSMenuItems.

For achieving this, I'm using code given below:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSArray alloc]init];
dirContents=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:updated error:nil];
```

This code is working but only in one folder. Strange but it is true. I have tried the same code for other folders but it gives nil value in `dirContents`.

So how can I access the list of all the contents of a selected folder?

Comment: Consider that in a sandboxed app the access to folders outside of the container is restricted. And it's highly recommended to use the `URL` related API of `NSFileManager`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to track the access error.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSArray alloc]init];
dirContents=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:updated error:&error];

if(error){
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

Make sure you use relative path to the  directory, if the app is sandboxed, not absolute path.

```
NSURL *containerUrl =[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"Your.app.container.id"];
path = [[containerUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"your/folder/path"] path];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSArray*)allURLs:(NSURL*)url{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    NSURL *bundleURL = url;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:bundleURL
                                          includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                                                             options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                        errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"[Error] %@ (%@)", error, url);
                                             return url;
                                         }];

    NSMutableArray *mutableFileURLs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSURL *fileURL in enumerator) {
        NSString *filename;
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&filename forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

        NSNumber *isDirectory;
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];

        // Skip directories with '_' prefix, for example
        if ([filename hasPrefix:@"_"] && [isDirectory boolValue]) {
            [enumerator skipDescendants];
            continue;
        }

        if (![isDirectory boolValue]) {
            [mutableFileURLs addObject:fileURL];
        }
    }


    return mutableFileURLs;
}
```